# Function Information and Derivatives

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

There are two ways I can formulate this question.

1) Say I have a continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$ such that $f\in{C^\infty}$. This is all I know about the function. What is the minimum region over which I must know the value of the function in order to compute the first derivative, second, or kth derivative?

2) Say I have a continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^m$ such that $f\in{C^\infty}$ and is also non zero at a single point $\mathbf{x}$. In addition, I also know the function has higher order non zero derivatives up to kth order at $\mathbf{x}$. How does the existence of the non zero derivatives imply the function $f$ is non zero over a given region about $\mathbf{x}$ and can we say anything about the size of the region over which $f$ is non zero?

Essentially what I believe I'm asking is what can non zero derivatives tell us about the region over which a function is defined and the value of the function. Does their existence imply $f$ is "locally" non zero about $\mathbf{x}$ or do they indicate $f$ is "non-locally" non zero about $\mathbf{x}$? Note I'm aware I'm assuming that the existence of non zero higher order derivatives implies at least the function has non zero values about $\mathbf{x}$ as this is what my intuition indicates. This may be faulty.

Comment: Are you refering to the derivatives for all points or just a single point?

Comment: In general, information about the derivatives of a function at a single point can be obtained by knowing the behavior of the function, i.e. its values, in a neighborhood of the point (e.g. some open bubble in $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the point). That said, the reverse is a bit trickier, especially in the way you've phrased it. Knowing that the first 10 billion derivatives of a function are nonzero at some point $x$ doesn't really tell you that the function is nonzero at that point, since antiderivatives aren't unique up to additive constants, which easily alter the value at a single point.